# I have a question regarding Teradata query implementation

Tags: teradata

Scenario:-

If col 1 has values start with # then cut first 8 characters
And If it ends with AB and and starts with X use only middle

Please help me give an idea how it looks like in Teradata coding

Comment: Can you clarify what "use only middle" means here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "use only middle" means everything between the starting `X` and the ending `AB` for that second criteria in your question, you have a few options.

1.Use `regexp_replace()`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('XSOMETHINGAB', '^X(.*)AB$|^#(.{1,8}).*', '\1\2');

SOMETHING

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('#SOMETHINGAB', '^X(.*)AB$|^#(.{1,8}).*', '\1\2')

SOMETHIN
```

2.Or a case statement:

```
SELECT 
'XSOMETHINGAB' as mystring, 
CASE 
    WHEN mystring LIKE '#%' THEN SUBSTRING(mystring FROM 2 FOR 8)
    WHEN mystring LIKE 'X%AB' THEN SUBSTRING(mystring FROM 2 FOR "LENGTH"(mystring) - 3)
    ELSE mystring
    END
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill I will try and implement...Thanks for Replying 